# BeautifulSoup does not return gives error for both find_all() and/or find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to the prices of sold houses in zillow and here is my attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

headers = {
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1673152744.1651941872; zjs_user_id=null; zg_anonymous_id=%2268ca4597-57e2-4569-8b51-b4d390baabfd%22; zjs_anonymous_id=%22313d303c-4a98-4878-a4c0-4ba758bf85cb%22; _gcl_au=1.1.2045578279.1651941873; _pxvid=f8a14e39-ce24-11ec-b5d5-614e7a4a506c; _fbp=fb.1.1651941873087.720309583; __pdst=44605a1f38874dd296884caee932b53e; _cs_c=0; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU16UXpOREZqTURjdE4yTXhNUzAwT0dGbUxUazVZbVV0TURFME16UXhZekJsWldVeA; _gac_UA-21174015-56=1.1652736155.CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMWQrrMU1bgTf5w5pLscs6beK6W4Z5ZMnpvg1tCQL2O4ELmoaldWpsRoC-pIQAvD_BwE; _gcl_aw=GCL.1652736156.CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMWQrrMU1bgTf5w5pLscs6beK6W4Z5ZMnpvg1tCQL2O4ELmoaldWpsRoC-pIQAvD_BwE; zguid=24|%24313d303c-4a98-4878-a4c0-4ba758bf85cb; zgsession=1|49bf6394-c128-46ed-b60c-f44845eee0a4; pxcts=f2ff6767-e881-11ec-8d10-7654455a784e; DoubleClickSession=true; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; g_state={"i_p":1659752164993,"i_l":4}; KruxPixel=true; KruxAddition=true; _gid=GA1.2.156427582.1658955938; _gat=1; _pxff_bsco=1; _pxff_tm=1; _hp2_id.1215457233=%7B%22userId%22%3A%227482855519340279%22%2C%22pageviewId%22%3A%224371827357917612%22%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%224330573612186749%22%2C%22identity%22%3A%22313d303c4a984878a4c04ba758bf85cb%22%2C%22trackerVersion%22%3A%224.0%22%2C%22identityField%22%3Anull%2C%22isIdentified%22%3A1%7D; _cs_id=9a93c00e-66bc-a34d-9080-f8cd9c853b2e.1651941873.9.1658955940.1658955940.1.1686105873464; _hp2_ses_props.1215457233=%7B%22ts%22%3A1658955939824%2C%22d%22%3A%22www.zillow.com%22%2C%22h%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D; _clck=1k688ws|1|f3i|0; _cs_s=1.5.0.1658957740562; JSESSIONID=37F330B360B367C5078D1CE3FF752613; utag_main=v_id:01809f68962500ab9295fcec46b00507a00e607200ac8$_sn:22$_se:1$_ss:1$_st:1658957739912$dc_visit:19$ses_id:1658955939912%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$dcsyncran:1%3Bexp-session$tdsyncran:1%3Bexp-session$dc_event:1%3Bexp-session$dc_region:us-west-2%3Bexp-session$ttd_uuid:723f3b30-f651-4ab7-912e-0dafadc410cc%3Bexp-session; _px3=d6eb87ce838da8d0f897420181a1a09b93bf7e2e5d5a9d5dfabd24c4f692ea71:dWq5/77J71LgkUsG5d/LHg0weAN9ckAV4QNy49z45HTlSZSC5vXbFwcCCQ1Zyrd5Oq4NlWqNJ7ENbBbVCZBybA==:1000:5YQlounZImHX7tzdjZtU5eX+eO9iMxj+3TIPGnXBEN1ruG7BTio/CkmZPae4Ao4nTLxdH2fy6ib3Wk8vaRC8idutWcjmk/Jq2GFdXMM/XfDPy/NduJwHvPxvMFSKpAfjTP3ft8ov/3Q51GG95xdb76C1nRlJMzk07PXorzo7fenKdi54T+i39o6jivsYkqC8oNfILDufpVp0Ysc13Q8kbw==; _uetsid=de540c900def11ed8ba92b524accb8aa; _uetvid=3adaf020bfc911eb8f701323ea2a2b57; AWSALB=WLxAcs6r29liHnv/H9IcuoLOTwb14rPMHRpRfmgrNVjAG19aFtvLCBgTMRPBWtN2HTGmmm4UQn3HkwtALP77x+MNqugTlablwPHxlXf6F8vLPvY+IT+YRVRNYGPj; AWSALBCORS=WLxAcs6r29liHnv/H9IcuoLOTwb14rPMHRpRfmgrNVjAG19aFtvLCBgTMRPBWtN2HTGmmm4UQn3HkwtALP77x+MNqugTlablwPHxlXf6F8vLPvY+IT+YRVRNYGPj; search=6|1661547971145%7Crect%3D37.857199931363425%252C-122.28295413378906%252C37.693293130474025%252C-122.58370486621094%26rid%3D20330%26disp%3Dmap%26mdm%3Dauto%26p%3D1%26z%3D1%26fs%3D0%26fr%3D0%26mmm%3D0%26rs%3D1%26ah%3D0%26singlestory%3D0%26housing-connector%3D0%26abo%3D0%26garage%3D0%26pool%3D0%26ac%3D0%26waterfront%3D0%26finished%3D0%26unfinished%3D0%26cityview%3D0%26mountainview%3D0%26parkview%3D0%26waterview%3D0%26hoadata%3D1%26zillow-owned%3D0%263dhome%3D0%26featuredMultiFamilyBuilding%3D0%09%0920330%09%09%09%09%09%09; _clsk=1gwrgb2|1658955971691|3|0|d.clarity.ms/collect',
'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


params = {
'searchQueryState': '{"pagination":{},"usersSearchTerm":"San Francisco, CA","mapBounds":{"west":-122.58370486621094,"east":-122.28295413378906,"south":37.693293130474025,"north":37.857199931363425},"regionSelection":[{"regionId":20330,"regionType":6}],"isMapVisible":false,"filterState":{"sort":{"value":"globalrelevanceex"},"fsba":{"value":false},"fsbo":{"value":false},"nc":{"value":false},"fore":{"value":false},"cmsn":{"value":false},"auc":{"value":false},"rs":{"value":true},"ah":{"value":true}},"isListVisible":true,"mapZoom":12}'
}

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/sold'

houses = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params = params)
houses_cards = BeautifulSoup(houses.text)
cards = houses_cards.find_all('ul', {'class':'List-c11n-8-69-2__sc-1smrmqp-0'})
cards.find_all('article', {'class': 'list-card list-card-additional-attribution'})
```

I get the following error after tuning the last line:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/fd/72yblq016950hs5y1xzckf_c0000gn/T/ipykernel_16240/2960189247.py in <module>
----> 1 cards.find_all('article', {'class': 'list-card list-card-additional-attribution'})

/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2288         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
   2289         raise AttributeError(
-> 2290             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2291         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

if I run `cards.find('article', {'class': 'list-card list-card-additional-attribution'})`, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/fd/72yblq016950hs5y1xzckf_c0000gn/T/ipykernel_16240/3133868743.py in <module>
----> 1 cards.find('article', {'class': 'list-card list-card-additional-attribution'})

/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2288         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
   2289         raise AttributeError(
-> 2290             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2291         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: `.find()`/`.find_all()` can work only on single result but `.find_all()` gives many results - and this needs `for`-loop to run it on every result separatelly.

Answer (score 1):

Inspite of the correct html content selection, you can't scrape  all the data items from the webpage, You will get only 6 to 8 items because content is under html comment inside a script tag. See the provement step by step.

**Example with bs4:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

headers = {
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.1673152744.1651941872; zjs_user_id=null; zg_anonymous_id=%2268ca4597-57e2-4569-8b51-b4d390baabfd%22; zjs_anonymous_id=%22313d303c-4a98-4878-a4c0-4ba758bf85cb%22; _gcl_au=1.1.2045578279.1651941873; _pxvid=f8a14e39-ce24-11ec-b5d5-614e7a4a506c; _fbp=fb.1.1651941873087.720309583; __pdst=44605a1f38874dd296884caee932b53e; _cs_c=0; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU16UXpOREZqTURjdE4yTXhNUzAwT0dGbUxUazVZbVV0TURFME16UXhZekJsWldVeA; _gac_UA-21174015-56=1.1652736155.CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMWQrrMU1bgTf5w5pLscs6beK6W4Z5ZMnpvg1tCQL2O4ELmoaldWpsRoC-pIQAvD_BwE; _gcl_aw=GCL.1652736156.CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMWQrrMU1bgTf5w5pLscs6beK6W4Z5ZMnpvg1tCQL2O4ELmoaldWpsRoC-pIQAvD_BwE; zguid=24|%24313d303c-4a98-4878-a4c0-4ba758bf85cb; zgsession=1|49bf6394-c128-46ed-b60c-f44845eee0a4; pxcts=f2ff6767-e881-11ec-8d10-7654455a784e; DoubleClickSession=true; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; g_state={"i_p":1659752164993,"i_l":4}; KruxPixel=true; KruxAddition=true; _gid=GA1.2.156427582.1658955938; _gat=1; _pxff_bsco=1; _pxff_tm=1; _hp2_id.1215457233=%7B%22userId%22%3A%227482855519340279%22%2C%22pageviewId%22%3A%224371827357917612%22%2C%22sessionId%22%3A%224330573612186749%22%2C%22identity%22%3A%22313d303c4a984878a4c04ba758bf85cb%22%2C%22trackerVersion%22%3A%224.0%22%2C%22identityField%22%3Anull%2C%22isIdentified%22%3A1%7D; _cs_id=9a93c00e-66bc-a34d-9080-f8cd9c853b2e.1651941873.9.1658955940.1658955940.1.1686105873464; _hp2_ses_props.1215457233=%7B%22ts%22%3A1658955939824%2C%22d%22%3A%22www.zillow.com%22%2C%22h%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D; _clck=1k688ws|1|f3i|0; _cs_s=1.5.0.1658957740562; JSESSIONID=37F330B360B367C5078D1CE3FF752613; utag_main=v_id:01809f68962500ab9295fcec46b00507a00e607200ac8$_sn:22$_se:1$_ss:1$_st:1658957739912$dc_visit:19$ses_id:1658955939912%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$dcsyncran:1%3Bexp-session$tdsyncran:1%3Bexp-session$dc_event:1%3Bexp-session$dc_region:us-west-2%3Bexp-session$ttd_uuid:723f3b30-f651-4ab7-912e-0dafadc410cc%3Bexp-session; _px3=d6eb87ce838da8d0f897420181a1a09b93bf7e2e5d5a9d5dfabd24c4f692ea71:dWq5/77J71LgkUsG5d/LHg0weAN9ckAV4QNy49z45HTlSZSC5vXbFwcCCQ1Zyrd5Oq4NlWqNJ7ENbBbVCZBybA==:1000:5YQlounZImHX7tzdjZtU5eX+eO9iMxj+3TIPGnXBEN1ruG7BTio/CkmZPae4Ao4nTLxdH2fy6ib3Wk8vaRC8idutWcjmk/Jq2GFdXMM/XfDPy/NduJwHvPxvMFSKpAfjTP3ft8ov/3Q51GG95xdb76C1nRlJMzk07PXorzo7fenKdi54T+i39o6jivsYkqC8oNfILDufpVp0Ysc13Q8kbw==; _uetsid=de540c900def11ed8ba92b524accb8aa; _uetvid=3adaf020bfc911eb8f701323ea2a2b57; AWSALB=WLxAcs6r29liHnv/H9IcuoLOTwb14rPMHRpRfmgrNVjAG19aFtvLCBgTMRPBWtN2HTGmmm4UQn3HkwtALP77x+MNqugTlablwPHxlXf6F8vLPvY+IT+YRVRNYGPj; AWSALBCORS=WLxAcs6r29liHnv/H9IcuoLOTwb14rPMHRpRfmgrNVjAG19aFtvLCBgTMRPBWtN2HTGmmm4UQn3HkwtALP77x+MNqugTlablwPHxlXf6F8vLPvY+IT+YRVRNYGPj; search=6|1661547971145%7Crect%3D37.857199931363425%252C-122.28295413378906%252C37.693293130474025%252C-122.58370486621094%26rid%3D20330%26disp%3Dmap%26mdm%3Dauto%26p%3D1%26z%3D1%26fs%3D0%26fr%3D0%26mmm%3D0%26rs%3D1%26ah%3D0%26singlestory%3D0%26housing-connector%3D0%26abo%3D0%26garage%3D0%26pool%3D0%26ac%3D0%26waterfront%3D0%26finished%3D0%26unfinished%3D0%26cityview%3D0%26mountainview%3D0%26parkview%3D0%26waterview%3D0%26hoadata%3D1%26zillow-owned%3D0%263dhome%3D0%26featuredMultiFamilyBuilding%3D0%09%0920330%09%09%09%09%09%09; _clsk=1gwrgb2|1658955971691|3|0|d.clarity.ms/collect',
'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


params = {
'searchQueryState': '{"pagination":{},"usersSearchTerm":"San Francisco, CA","mapBounds":{"west":-122.58370486621094,"east":-122.28295413378906,"south":37.693293130474025,"north":37.857199931363425},"regionSelection":[{"regionId":20330,"regionType":6}],"isMapVisible":false,"filterState":{"sort":{"value":"globalrelevanceex"},"fsba":{"value":false},"fsbo":{"value":false},"nc":{"value":false},"fore":{"value":false},"cmsn":{"value":false},"auc":{"value":false},"rs":{"value":true},"ah":{"value":true}},"isListVisible":true,"mapZoom":12}'
}

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/sold'

houses = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params = params)
houses_cards = BeautifulSoup(houses.text,'lxml')
card = houses_cards.find('ul', {'class':'List-c11n-8-69-2__sc-1smrmqp-0'})
cards=card.find_all('li', {'class': 'ListItem-c11n-8-69-2__sc-10e22w8-0 srp__hpnp3q-0 enEXBq'})

for item in cards:
    price= item.select_one('div[class="StyledPropertyCardDataArea-c11n-8-69-2__sc-yipmu-0 kJFQQX"] span')
    price=price.get_text(strip=True) if price else None
    print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
$1.72M
$1.31M
$2.66M
$1.90M
$2.05M
$4.50M
$515,000
$1.38M
$1.12M
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

**From script tag:**

```
import requests
import re
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.zillow.com/san-francisco-ca/sold/1_p/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-123.05611697558594%2C%22east%22%3A-122.21016970996094%2C%22south%22%3A37.416218151120056%2C%22north%22%3A37.948763955871286%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A20330%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22rs%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D',headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

data = json.loads(re.search(r'!--(\{"queryState".*?)-->', r.text).group(1))

for item in data['cat1']['searchResults']['listResults']:
    price= item['soldPrice'] 
    print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
$1.72M
$1.31M
$2.66M
$1.90M
$2.05M
$4.50M
$515,000
$1.38M
$1.12M
$3.42M
$1.66M
$2.42M
$1.40M
$1.50M
$2.12M
$635,000
$1.40M
$1.02M
$9.81M
$1.20M
$509,000
$1.16M
$2.22M
$1.16M
$1.30M
$1.05M
$1.46M
$1.12M
$1.54M
$1.72M
$1.50M
$1.90M
$1.11M
$875,000
$540,000
$1.20M
$2.90M
$2.08M
$1.68M
$2.00M
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am not familiar with this approach though. How did you come up with the url in your requests.get method.? If I copy the url it would not have  `sold/1_p/searchQueryStat` but instead it has `sold/?searchQueryStat`

Comment: also in your approach, how can you scarp through different pages. Your script shows the first page only

Comment: could you please complete the answer

Comment: Sorry for that I made pagination several ways they are working but only single page is unique  rest are duplicates .If you want to see the solutions no problem

Comment: can we try with `html_parser` ?

Comment: No, most likely html_parser may not work. It's complex url encoded. You have to rebuild the pagination encoded url  following cookie and headers.  In this case scrapy is super helpful. Alternatively, there  are 20 urls here , you can collect those url and make a list and scrape using selenium. But if you are familiar with scrapy that's the best way to use API

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `cards` is a `bs4.element.ResultSet` object which has no `find_all()` or `find()` attribute associated with it. Those attributes only exist for `bs4.BeautifulSoup` objects, such as `houses_cards`, hence the error.

If you want to filter/search from the values of `cards`, then you can iterate over it and select values accordingly.

Otherwise, try the following:

```
houses_cards = BeautifulSoup(houses.text)
cards_ul = houses_cards.find_all('ul', {'class':'List-c11n-8-69-2__sc-1smrmqp-0'})
cards_article = houses_cards.find_all('article', {'class': 'list-card list-card-additional-attribution'})
```

Comment: cards_article is an empty list

Comment: Then use different parameters for `find_all()`?

Answer (score 0):

`.find()`/`.find_all()` can work only on single item but `.find_all()` gives many items - and this needs to use `for`-loop to run it on every item separatelly.

```
cards = houses_cards.find_all(...)

#all_results = []

for item in cards:
    results = item.find_all('article', {'class': 'list-card list-card-additional-attribution'})
    #all_results += results
```

Comment: what is cards in your example?

Comment: it is `cards` from your code. `cards = houses_cards.find_all(...)`